# $scope.$watch a div tag with Angular and Ionic/Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use QRCode Read/scan in a Cordova application. QRCode the response of QRCode is in the qrcode.result variable.

I'need watch a div and process when it changes. The process consist on the navigation to a different html. For example, if the qrcode.result is equals to the sentence "ok". the UI must be changes to "principal.html". In case of the qrcode.result equals to "help" the application must be changes to "help.html". Could you help-me ?

My code is:

```
<!--display result-->                
<div id="result" class="col" ng-model="result">{{result}}</div>
```

and the controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
    load();

    $scope.$watch('result', function(newVal, oldVal){
        alert(qrcode.result);
    }, true);  
});
```

Comment: why you have putted ng-model for `div`?

Comment: @pankajparkar i started with angular and ionic...

Comment: what is `qrcode` in your controller?

Comment: qrcode is the variable of the qrcode.js library https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/blob/master/src/qrcode.js. I use it to obtain a QRCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this approach

```
<!--display result-->                
<div id="result" class="col">{{result}}</div>
```

You don't need `ng-model`, which is usually for input.

And for angular side...

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
    load();

    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return qrcode.result;
    }, function(newVal){
        $scope.result = newVal;
    }, true);  
});
```

You can watch out-for-$scope variables with function expression.

Comment: I update the questions, to precis more about the process when I get the qrcode

Comment: You may use `ng-include` directive or `ngRoute` module, depending on your preference. For example using `ng-include`, `<div ng-include="result === 'ok' ? 'principal.html' : 'help.html'"></div>`. (little bit messy code by the way)